# Looking for a proxy server application that reroutes traffic based on http status code

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

I know that I can write what I'm describing here with Python, Go and other programming languages but I'm looking for a ready-made solution.

I need an application that does this scenario:

1. It exposes an HTTP proxy, which is available on for example `127.0.0.1:2000`
2. When it receives a request, it checks the reachability of the destination of the request via *checking the HTTP response status codes:

   a. If the response status code is `200`, forwards the request to `127.0.0.1:2001`

   b. If the response status code is NOT `200`, forwards the request to `127.0.0.1:2002`

Is there an application that can create such a proxy?

- The equivalent command for checking for the reachability of the destination of the request using `curl` can be like this:

`curl -Is https://unix.stackexchange.com | head -1`